# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x}{(x^2 + 4)^5} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{x}{(x^2 + 4)^5} \mathrm{d}x.$$

If I transfer $(x^2 + 4)^5$ to the numerator, how do I integrate?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you mean by "transfer" but:

**Hint** Note that $d(x^2 + 4) = 2 x \,dx$, so the $x$ in the numerator suggests a particular substitution.

Comment: Why the downvote? This hint seems perfectly standard to me.

Comment: Perfectly correct ... and more since it is the key. $+1$ so

Answer (score 3):

Put $u = x^2+4 \implies du = 2x\,dx\implies x\,dx = \frac 12 du$.

$$ \begin{align}\int \frac{x}{(x^2 + 4)^5} \mathrm{d}x &= \frac 12\int u^{-5} \,du\\ & = \frac 12 \left(\frac {u^{-4}}{-4}\right) +c \\ &= -\frac{1}{8u^4} + c \\ &= -\frac {1}{8(x^2 + 4)^4} + c\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

with $u = x^2 + 4$:
$$  \int  (x^2 + 4)^{-5 }  {x dx}  
=   \frac 12 \int u^{-5} {du}
=  - \frac 1{8} u^{-4} 
=  - \frac 1{8} (x^2 + 4)^{-4} 
$$